# question on congruo and modulo

Tags: number-theory

If a is any positive integer

Prove that $a^3 \equiv\pm 0,-1,+1 \ mod{7}$

I have tried by taking different cases but that goes very big. Does any one has any short method for proving this...

Comment: Well, there are only seven cases to consider, viz. $0. \pm1, \pm2, \pm3$. That doesn't look very big.

Comment: We need never take the cube of anything bigger than $3$, so it is a short calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $a\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\pmod7$

$a^3\equiv0,\pm1,\pm8\equiv\pm1,\pm3^3\equiv\mp1$

as $8\equiv1,27\equiv-1\pmod7$

Answer (score 1):

Your number $a$ can be thought of as one of the following: $7n$, $7n+1$, $7n+2$, $7n+3$, $7n+4$, $7n+5$, $7n+6$ where $n$ is an integer.

You then need to look at each case:

$(7n)^3\equiv0\pmod{7}$

$(7n+1)^3=\equiv 1^3\equiv 1\pmod{7}$

$(7n+2)^3\equiv 2^3\equiv 8\equiv 1\pmod{7}$

$(7n+3)^3\equiv 3^3\equiv 27\equiv 6\equiv -1\pmod{7}$

$(7n+4)^3\equiv 4^3\equiv (-3)^3\equiv -27\equiv -6\equiv 1\pmod{7}$

$(7n+5)^3\equiv 5^3\equiv (-2)^3\equiv -8\equiv -1\pmod{7}$

$(7n+6)^3\equiv 6^3\equiv (-1)^3\equiv -1\pmod{7}$

$$$$
Note: To be more concise we could have thought of the numbers as being one of the following: $7n$, $7n\pm1$, $7n\pm2$, $7n\pm3$ and done it in only four cases rather than seven.

$(7n)^3\equiv0\pmod{7}$

$(7n+\pm1)^3=\equiv (\pm1)^3\equiv \pm1\pmod{7}$

$(7n\pm2)^3\equiv (\pm2)^3\equiv \pm8\equiv \mp1\pmod{7}$

$(7n\pm3)^3\equiv (\pm3)^3\equiv \pm27\equiv \pm6\equiv \mp1\pmod{7}$

Answer (score 0):

If for any odd prime $p|a,a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv0\pmod7$

Else using Fermat's Little Theorem, $$p|(a^{p-1}-1)=(a^{(p-1)/2}-1)(a^{(p-1)/2}+1)$$

$\implies p$ divides at least (in fact exactly one of )  $$a^{(p-1)/2}-1, a^{(p-1)/2}+1$$